# RoutePrefix in web api dont start controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I need to start Index from Controller before opening page and that was working but when i added RoutePrefix controller didn't want to start. What should be done so i can start controller even with RoutePrefix.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "main", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/main")]
public class MainController : ApiController
{
    private static List<Korisnik> adminlist = new List<Korisnik>();
    private static List<Vozac> vozaclist = new List<Vozac>();
    private static List<Korisnik> korisniklist = new List<Korisnik>();

    [HttpGet, Route("")]
    public RedirectResult Index()
    {
        ReadFromXML(Enums.Uloga.Dispecer);
        var requestUri = Request.RequestUri;
        return Redirect(requestUri.AbsoluteUri + "Content/index.html");
    }
```

Comment: How do you call the api? which url

Comment: i don`t understand program is called on just my computer in Visual Studio, its more like simulation of service. And before RoutePrefix when was started first he ho in MainController and start action Index but after RoutePrefix i dont know how to get to ManController class

Comment: So when u run VS in debug mode, before routeprefix the controller method were called directly?

Comment: What response are you getting after adding RoutePrefix?